# How to script a schema change for one of my Mongo collections within Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Right now, the structure of my Programs collection is:

```
{ 
  Name : 'Jane Doe',
  Year : 'c16',
  CampYear: 'ssipc16',
  RoomWk1 :'21A', 
  RoomWk2: '22A',
  RoomWk3: '33B',
  RoomWk4: '33B',
  RoomWk5: '25B'
  Week1: '1'
  ...
}
```

I want to change it to:

```
{
  Name: 'Jan Doe',
  Year: { 
          'c16': {
                   RoomWk1: '21A',
                   RoomWk2: '22A',
                   RoomWk3: '33B',
                   RoomWk4: '33B',
                   RoomWk5: '25B'
                  }
        }
   CampYear: 'ssipc16',
   ...
}
```

The change would be just to nest the RoomWk1 - RoomWk5 under the Year field. How could I do this? Should it be done within the mongo shell in Meteor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there aren't a lot of `program` documents, you can do something like this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const Programs = new Mongo.Collection('programs');

Meteor.startup(() => {
  const programs = Programs.find().fetch();

  for (let program of programs) {
    const { Year, RoomWk1, RoomWk2, RoomWk3, RoomWk4, RoomWk5 } = program;
    program.Year = { [Year]: { RoomWk1, RoomWk2, RoomWk3, RoomWk4, RoomWk5 } };
    delete program.RoomWk1;
    delete program.RoomWk2;
    delete program.RoomWk3;
    delete program.RoomWk4;
    delete program.RoomWk5;

    Programs.update(program._id, program);
  }

});
```

It's a little crude because it loads each `program` into memory and then completely replaces it in the db, but that should work in cases where the collection size doesn't exceed a few thousand documents.

For more sophisticated techniques, I'd recommend reading the [migrations](http://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#migrations) section of the guide.